# Oracle 12.1.0.2.0 EM port 5500 not open

Tags: oracle-12c

After Install Oracle 12.1.0.2.0 i can not access https://10.10.20.156:5500/em

```
 netstat -a  
 not show port 5500  

C:\Users\Administrator>lsnrctl status

LSNRCTL for 64-bit Windows: Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production on 03-AUG-2019 16:53:26

Copyright (c) 1991, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=10.10.20.156)(PORT=1521)))  
STATUS of the LISTENER  
------------------------  
Alias                     LISTENER  
Version                   TNSLSNR for 64-bit Windows: Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production  
Start Date                03-AUG-2019 16:39:23  
Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 14 min. 7 sec  
Trace Level               off  
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication  
SNMP                      OFF  
Listener Parameter File    
C:\app\oracle\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\network\admin\listener.ora
Listener Log File         C:\app\oracle\diag\tnslsnr\oracle12c\listener\alert\log.xml  
Listening Endpoints Summary...  
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=10.10.20.156)(PORT=1521)))  
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(PIPENAME=\\.\pipe\EXTPROC1521ipc)))  
Services Summary...  
Service "CLRExtProc" has 1 instance(s).  
  Instance "CLRExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...  
The command completed successfully  



SQL*Plus: Release 12.1.0.2.0 Production on Sat Aug 3 16:58:09 2019  
Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.  
Connected to:  
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Advanced Analytics and Real Application Testing options  
SQL> select dbms_xdb_config.gethttpsport() from  dual;  
DBMS_XDB_CONFIG.GETHTTPSPORT()   
------------------------------   
5500  
SQL> select dbms_xdb_config.gethttpport() from  dual;
DBMS_XDB_CONFIG.GETHTTPPORT()  
-----------------------------
2200  
SQL>
```

Thanks in advance.
Edit : here is "lsnrctl services"

```
C:\Users\Administrator>lsnrctl services

LSNRCTL for 64-bit Windows: Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production on 03-AUG-2019 18:23:32

Copyright (c) 1991, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=10.10.20.156)(PORT=1521)))
Services Summary...
Service "CLRExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "CLRExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
    Handler(s):
      "DEDICATED" established:0 refused:0
         LOCAL SERVER
The command completed successfully
```

Comment: Did you start EM?

Comment: @MichaelKutz Sorry, I am newbie oracle. How to start EM? On my oracle 12c emctl is not found.